# multiple sequence update postgres

Tags: postgresql

I have a table, on which I have added a new column *nxvl*.

I need to do something like this

```
UPDATE table1
SET nxvl = nexval('my_sequence_1')
from table2 
where table1.col_id = table2.id and table2.val_col=1
order by table1.date

UPDATE table1
SET nxvl = nexval('my_sequence_2')
from table2 
where table1.col_id = table2.id and table2.val_col=2
order by table1.date
```

Postgres doesn't allow *order by* on *update*

It has around 100,000 rows.
Can it be done with Update command. Right now there are only 2 values in *`val_col`* ie *1 & 2*

Since it's a one time thing, I don't mind doing it with functions and looping through each row and update.

For knowledge wondering if there's a better way of achieving it.

Using Postgres 12.2

Answer (score 0):

You can set the order and fetch the associated sequence value in a subquery, then update table (without even considering the update order)

```
UPDATE table1
SET nxvl = a.seq
FROM
 ( select table1.id, nexval('my_sequence_1') seq
  from table1 
   join table2 
     on table1.col_id = table2.id 
        and table2.val_col=1
  order by table1.date
 ) a
WHERE table1.id = a.id;
```

Comment: I had written a function to do it
Should have closed it.My mistake.
But thanks...